# Rabbitmq unroutable messages published to the default exchange?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have just learned I have a high number of unroutable messages being published to the default exchange.

Because this is the default exchange, I am having a hard time tracking down the source of these unroutable messages. If this was not the default exchange I could find the publishing client by searching my code base by exchange name.  Additionally, I can't effectively bind to the default exchange because I do not know the routing keys of the messages being published.

Is there any way I can find these messages without starting/stopping all my clients one at a time?

Comment: Tried configuring the alternate exchange, but we only found unroutable messages to normal exchanges. Didn't get anything from the default exchange.

Comment: Turns out this is a bug in rabbitmq statistics and that I do not actually have unroutable message. However, I would still be unable to solve this problem if it did in fact exist. It might be solvable with with `alternative exchange`, but not sure.

Comment: Hey just curious if there's any links to the bug you mentioned - I _think_ I'm experiencing the same but would be good to know for sure